# Remainder of a square

Tags: chinese-remainder-theorem

Let R represent the function that, given two inputs, a and b, returns the remainder of a when divided by b. E.g.:

if $$a = bx + c$$, then $$R(a, x) = c$$

This remainder function has a lot of properties. For example, one property says that
$$R(a, x)*R(b, x) = R(a*b, x)$$
and that implies another property
$$R(a, x)*R(a, x) = R(a^2, x)$$
Is there any similar property that allow us to compute the condition?:
$$R(a, x^2)$$

Comment: In your definition, you should state that you are working with natural numbers (including $0$) and state that $x > 0$ and $c < x$. You can't express $R(a, x^2)$ in terms of $R(a, x)$ except in the trivial case when $x = 1$, because $R(a, x)$ loses more information about $a$ then does $R(a, x^2)$: e.g., when $x = 2$, the former has $2$ possible values while the latter has $4$.

Comment: $R(a, x)R(b, x) = R(ab, x)$ is not true. You need to reduce the LHS mod $x$. So, it's $R(R(a, x)R(b, x),x) = R(ab, x)$. That's why Gauss' congruence notation is superior.